# Wpf/SL charts - Pie tooltip

Tags: wpf, silverlight, charts

I want to set a toolTip on each of the data Points of the pie charts.
I know how to do that, but as you can see in the attached picture, 
the toolTips look different according to the data points directions.

Someone has an idea how can I do that ? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the WPF/Silverlight toolkit charts, see Bea Stollnitz's posts on that subject:

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=353

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=438

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=363

Her posts are very well-written - you should be able to find what you need there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for more advanced charts then you should give Telerik a try. Here is a demo page with [several chart samples](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/FirstLook) (that can include ToolTips).